# In ExtJS 4, why does setSrc() not update image

Tags: image, extjs

I have code that sets the src of an ExtJS 4 Image component.

```
me.cpuChart.setSrc(cpuChartUrl);
```

- set src first time - works fine
- set src to a different url - works fine
- set src back to the first url - DOES NOT UPDATE IMAGE

I tried calling these methods after calling setSrc() but does not update:

```
me.cpuChart.doComponentLayout();
me.cpuChart.updateLayout();
```

Any ideas? Seems like first url is being cached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the browser caching system... You could try to add a random string or query to the url to force the browser to reload the image from the server.

ex.:

```
cpuChartUrl = cpuChartUrl +'?dc=' + new Date().getTime();
me.cpuChart.setSrc(cpuChartUrl);
```